# How to mock firestore with mocha

Tags: typescript, google-cloud-firestore, jestjs, mocking, mocha.js

I have a simple wrapper function which returns a specific document from `firestore` like so:

```
export const fetchSettings = async (firestore):Promise<MyDocment>=>{
    try {
        const response = await firestore
            .collection('someCollection')
            .doc('someDoc')
            .get();
        const data = response.data()!;
        return {
          dataOne: data.someDataOne,
          dataTwo: data.someDataTwo
        };
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
        return error;
    }
};
```

This function is used in other function I want to test and therefore I would like to mock `firestore` to return a specific document the exact way this implementation would do.

How can I do this with mocha? With jest I could have something like `jest.fn(()=>Promise.resolve({dataOne:'somedata', dataTwo:'someotherdata'}));`

What is the mocha way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mocha doesn't have stub/mock functions. You should use some stub/mock library such as [sinonjs](https://sinonjs.org/).

E.g.

`fetchSettings.ts`:

```
interface MyDocment {}

export const fetchSettings = async (firestore): Promise<MyDocment> => {
  try {
    const response = await firestore.collection('someCollection').doc('someDoc').get();
    const data = response.data()!;
    return {
      dataOne: data.someDataOne,
      dataTwo: data.someDataTwo,
    };
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
    return error;
  }
};
```

`fetchSettings.test.ts`:

```
import { fetchSettings } from './fetchSettings';
import sinon from 'sinon';

describe('66868604', () => {
  it('should return data', async () => {
    const mData = {
      someDataOne: 'someDataOne',
      someDataTwo: 'someDataTwo',
    };
    const mRes = { data: sinon.stub().returns(mData) };
    const mFirestore = {
      collection: sinon.stub().returnsThis(),
      doc: sinon.stub().returnsThis(),
      get: sinon.stub().resolves(mRes),
    };
    const actual = await fetchSettings(mFirestore);
    sinon.assert.match(actual, { dataOne: 'someDataOne', dataTwo: 'someDataTwo' });
    sinon.assert.calledWithExactly(mFirestore.collection, 'someCollection');
    sinon.assert.calledWithExactly(mFirestore.doc, 'someDoc');
    sinon.assert.calledOnce(mFirestore.get);
    sinon.assert.calledOnce(mRes.data);
  });

  it('should handle error', async () => {
    const mErr = new Error('stackoverflow');
    const mFirestore = {
      collection: sinon.stub().returnsThis(),
      doc: sinon.stub().returnsThis(),
      get: sinon.stub().rejects(mErr),
    };
    const actual = await fetchSettings(mFirestore);
    sinon.assert.match(actual, mErr);
    sinon.assert.calledWithExactly(mFirestore.collection, 'someCollection');
    sinon.assert.calledWithExactly(mFirestore.doc, 'someDoc');
    sinon.assert.calledOnce(mFirestore.get);
  });
});
```

unit test result:

```
  66868604
    ✓ should return data
Error: stackoverflow
    at /Users/dulin/workspace/github.com/mrdulin/expressjs-research/src/stackoverflow/66868604/fetchSettings.test.ts:25:18
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at /Users/dulin/workspace/github.com/mrdulin/expressjs-research/src/stackoverflow/66868604/fetchSettings.test.ts:8:71
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at __awaiter (/Users/dulin/workspace/github.com/mrdulin/expressjs-research/src/stackoverflow/66868604/fetchSettings.test.ts:4:12)
    at Context.<anonymous> (/Users/dulin/workspace/github.com/mrdulin/expressjs-research/src/stackoverflow/66868604/fetchSettings.test.ts:24:40)
    at callFn (/Users/dulin/workspace/github.com/mrdulin/expressjs-research/node_modules/mocha/lib/runnable.js:364:21)
    at Test.Runnable.run (/Users/dulin/workspace/github.com/mrdulin/expressjs-research/node_modules/mocha/lib/runnable.js:352:5)
    at Runner.runTest (/Users/dulin/workspace/github.com/mrdulin/expressjs-research/node_modules/mocha/lib/runner.js:677:10)
    at /Users/dulin/workspace/github.com/mrdulin/expressjs-research/node_modules/mocha/lib/runner.js:801:12
    at next (/Users/dulin/workspace/github.com/mrdulin/expressjs-research/node_modules/mocha/lib/runner.js:594:14)
    at /Users/dulin/workspace/github.com/mrdulin/expressjs-research/node_modules/mocha/lib/runner.js:604:7
    at next (/Users/dulin/workspace/github.com/mrdulin/expressjs-research/node_modules/mocha/lib/runner.js:486:14)
    at Immediate.<anonymous> (/Users/dulin/workspace/github.com/mrdulin/expressjs-research/node_modules/mocha/lib/runner.js:572:5)
    at processImmediate (internal/timers.js:461:21)
    ✓ should handle error


  2 passing (10ms)

------------------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
File              | % Stmts | % Branch | % Funcs | % Lines | Uncovered Line #s 
------------------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
All files         |     100 |      100 |     100 |     100 |                   
 fetchSettings.ts |     100 |      100 |     100 |     100 |                   
------------------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
```

Comment: Tried this but it throws `TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'stub')` at line `const mRes = { data: sinon.stub().returns(mData) };`

Comment: How to stub query like ```db.doc(`/Client/${clientId}/Store/${storeId}`).get();```?

Answer (score 1):

Mocha doesn't include a mock library, so you need to [choose one](https://github.com/mochajs/mocha/wiki#mocks-stubs--spies) and add it manually to your tests.

Install sinon with

```
npm install sinon
```

Then include it in your code:

```
const sinon = require("sinon");
```

And use a [stub](https://sinonjs.org/releases/v10.0.0/stubs/) to create you function:

> Test stubs are functions (spies) with pre-programmed behavior.

```
// create an anonymous function stub
const stub = sinon.stub();
// set the resolved value (you want a promise)
stub.resolves({dataOne:'somedata', dataTwo:'someotherdata'});
// use returns if you want a plain function
// stub.returns(obj);
```

Now you can call `stub()` as your function.

You can also use [fakes](https://sinonjs.org/releases/v10.0.0/fakes/) or [mocks](https://sinonjs.org/releases/v10.0.0/mocks/) to achieve the same result.

Please take a look to the [setup documentation](https://sinonjs.org/releases/v10.0.0/general-setup/) to avoid common issues.

Comment: Tried this but it throws `TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'stub')`